# Initializing class asynchronously with Firebase async observeSingleEvent methods' completion handlers

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, async-await

I am instantiating a `User` class via a Firebase DataSnapshot. Upon calling the initializer `init(snapshot: DataSnapshot)`, I would like to asynchronously retrieve values from two distinct database references, namely `pictureRef` and `nameRef`, via the `getFirebasePictureURL` and `getFirebaseNameString` methods' @escaping completion handlers (using Firebase's `observeSingleEvent` method). However, console gives me two errors: **'self' captured by a closure before all members were initialized** and **'self' used in method call 'getFirebasePictureURL' before all stored properties are initialized**:

```
import Firebase

class User {

 var uid: String
 var fullname: String
 var pictureURL: URL

//DataSnapshot Initializer

init(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

self.uid = snapshot.key

getFirebasePictureURL(userId: uid) { (url) in

    self.getFirebaseNameString(userId: self.uid) { (fullName) in

        self.fullname = fullName
        self.profilePictureURL = url

    }
}

func getFirebasePictureURL(userId: String, completion: @escaping (_ url: URL) -> Void) {

    let currentUserId = userId
    //Firebase database picture reference
    let pictureRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "pictureChildPath")

    pictureRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        //Picture url string
        let pictureString = snapshot.value as! String

        //Completion handler (escaping)
        completion(URL(string: pictureString)!)

    })

}


func getFirebaseNameString(userId: String, completion: @escaping (_ fullName: String) -> Void) {

    let currentUserId = userId
    //Firebase database name reference
    let nameRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "nameChildPath")

    nameRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        let fullName = snapshot.value as? String

       //Completion handler (escaping)
        completion(fullName!)

        })
     }
  }
```

I am not too sure how I should initialize this asynchronously if this is the case.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class can not be initialized until  its all stored property initialized with default value or property should be optional or property value assigned in `init`  function  called **Designated Initializers**

> Designated initializers are the primary initializers for a class. A designated initializer fully initializes all properties introduced by that class and calls an appropriate superclass initializer to continue the initialization process up the superclass chain.

read this for more info. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html

So in your case you are trying `fullname` and `pictureURL` as stored property though your escaping closure (Async task) task which is not allowed because it is not fulfil the rule

As I mentioned earlier you have following  options

1. Assign some default value
2. Use optional value (best option you can handle error by checking optional later)

Hopefully it will helpful

Comment: Thanks! I'm a little confused what exactly you mean by the property value should be assigned in a designated initializer. Do you mind providing some code?

Comment: @SergioCharles What I mean is class initialising process is not completed until all stored property not initialized with value ,   you can do it like `var fullname: String = ""` or `var fullname: String? = nil`

Comment: I see what you mean, but wouldn't the program skip over the async completion handler because the assignment of something like `var fullname: String = ""` (or `var fullName: String? = nil`) is done synchronously? Would using dispatch group for the completion handler and then updating the assignment with a dispatch notify handler maybe work?

Comment: @SergioCharles **wouldn't the program skip over the async completion handler**  ==> NO , Compiler doesn't allow that,

Comment: @SergioCharles ** Would using dispatch group for the completion handler and then updating the assignment with a dispatch notify handler maybe work?** ==> Not it will also not work because it it also async task.

Comment: When I tried this method, the Firebase database has `full_name: ""` and `profile_picture: "initial"`. I did the above with `var fullname: String = ""` and `profilepicture: URL = URL(string: "initial")`, but they never actually updated.

Comment: @SergioCharles That's the different question you can ask new question with detailed explanation & Info

Comment: While it is not exactly the original question, the goal was still to instantiate the class with the asynchronous Firebase methods as I explained in the introduction.